# JS promises: How to chain `then` calls?

Tags: promise

I am trying to fetch some data, rework the object format and safe it in state. My last `.then` does not get the data from second one. I don't understand why this is the case.

```
fetch("http://myserver/switches")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      a = data.map(item => {
        var obj = {}
        obj = {value: item.switch, label: item.switch}
        return obj
      })
      console.log(a)
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      this.setState({ switches: data})
      console.log(this.state.switches)
      })
```

console log:

```
 >(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
 >undefined
 >undefined
```

Comment: The callback of your first `.then()` is completely synchronous, making it ripe for merging with the immediately following `.then()`. You will find that the two callbacks simplify to a single expression to give something of the general form `fetch(.....)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
 this.setState({ 'switches': data.map( ..... )});
});`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add in the second then() a statement `return a`
This will provide `a` as a parameter for the last then().

```
fetch("http://myserver/switches")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  a = data.map(item => {
    var obj = {}
    obj = {value: item.switch, label: item.switch}
    return obj
  })
  console.log(a)
  return a;
})
.then(data => {
  console.log(data)
  this.setState({ switches: data})
  console.log(this.state.switches)
  })
```

Comment: that worked, thx. I thought that a function always returns a value, as we can see with the response.json() call ?!

Comment: @Bastian: the response.json line is returned automatically because it's in the same line as the =>.
`.then(response => response.json())` is the same as 
`.then(response => {
    return response.json();
})`

Comment: Note that since the 2nd `.then()` has no asynchronous operations in it, you can just combine the code in the 2nd and 3rd `.then()`.  There is no need to have them separate.